# JS plugins conflict

Tags: javascript, google-maps, conflict, jquery

How can I get this two JS plugins together in the same file without conflicting with eachothers? The problem is that when I add the Google Maps plugin my Accordions stop working. Any ideas?
Please find the complete code here: http://jsfiddle.net/bBdSH/ Thank you!

```
/*----------------------------------------------- 
                A C C O R D I O N S
    ------------------------------------------------*/  
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var cur_stus;

        //close all on default
        $('.accordion .accordion-content').hide();
        $('.accordion .accordion-title').attr('stus', '');

        $('.accordion .accordion-title').click(function(){
            cur_stus = $(this).attr('stus');
            if(cur_stus != "active")
            {
                //reset everthing - content and attribute
                $('.accordion .accordion-content').slideUp();
                $('.accordion .accordion-title').attr('stus', '').removeClass('active');

                //then open the clicked data
                $(this).next().slideDown();
                $(this).attr('stus', 'active').addClass('active');
            }
            //Remove else part if do not want to close the current opened data
            else
            {
                $(this).next().slideUp();
                $(this).attr('stus', '').removeClass('active');
            }
            return false;
        });
    });
```

Comment: I'm not sure your fiddle is set up right I'm not seeing anything

Comment: I have just put the code on the javascript section on fiddle.